# How do I get django "Data too long for column '<column>' at row" errors to print the actual value?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a Django application. Sometimes in production I get an error when uploading data that one of the values is too long. It would be very helpful for debugging if I could see which value was the one that went over the limit. Can I configure this somehow? I'm using MySQL.

It would also be nice if I could enable/disable this on a per-model or column basis so that I don't leak user data to error logs.

Comment: This is not Django's error message, this is something that the *database* says.

Comment: Looking through the [MySQL source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/f8cdce86448a211511e8a039c62580ae16cb96f5/sql/rpl_gtid_persist.cc#L215), there's no configuration option for this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes and no. It's a sign that input validation does not match data validation. Typically a symptom of not using a ModelForm, but normal form with a hardcoded max_length for character fields that over time goes out of sync with the model. The other common case is DRF serializer method fields with the same flaw: no max length validation. So in short, you're catching something you could've caught earlier. Another not so common case, that was painful to debug when I ran into it, is a **faked** migration that increases the max length of a field.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, the form/serializer case doesn't work, cause the model CharField still should've caught it. So this leaves models not being in sync  with database storage and a faked/skipped/deleted/incorrectly squashed migration. Or perhaps an aggregation/concatenation done at field level, into a field that is too small.

Comment: @Melvyn the code is just `json.load`ing a json file uploaded through a form and then manually creating instances of `MyModel` and `.save`ing them, so the data is not being validated at all. You're right, I should change the code to use fields. I really appreciate you answering the underlying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating model instances from outside sources, one must take care to validate the input or have other guarantees that this data cannot violate constraints.

When not calling at least `full_clean()` on the model, but directly calling `save`, one bypasses Django's validators and will only get alerted to the problem by the database driver at which point it's harder to obtain diagnostics:

```py
class JsonImportManager(models.Manager):
    def import(self, json_string: str) -> int:
        data_list = json.loads(json_string)  # list of objects => list of dicts
        failed = 0
        for data in data_list:
            obj = self.model(**data)
            try:
                obj.full_clean()
            except ValidationError as e:
                print(e.message_dict)  # or use better formatting function
                failed += 1
            else:
                obj.save()

        return failed
```

This is of course very simple, but it's a good boilerplate to get started with.